Is reduced major axis regression a special case of total least squares?
Edit: It seems the answer to my first question is that the website has a typo. $\lambda = V_{y}/V_{x}$, NOT $\lambda = V_{x}/V_{y}$. But I'm still stumped on the second question about why it cannot be used for hypothesis testing. End Edit.
I am reading https://influentialpoints.com/Training/errors-in-variables_regression-principles-properties-assumptions.htm
which says total least squares has the following solution:

However, later it seems to indicate that reduced major axis regression is a special case of this when the ratio between the two variances is $\lambda = V_{x}/V_{y}$.   Specifically it says

However, it then gives the following formula as the solution for $\beta_{1}$:

However, I'm having trouble establishing this is really a special case of the more general solution above when $\lambda = V_{x}/V_{y}$.  When I try plugging this ratio in for $\lambda$ I cannot simplify it to the ratio of standard deviations which should be the solution.
I have two additional questions.  First conceptually it is not obvious why reducing the weighted sum of the squared vertical and squared horizontal residuals would give the same answer as reducing the product of the horizontal and vertical residuals, which I believe is what RMA (reduced major axis) regression is supposed to do.
Second, the consensus seems to be that RMA cannot be used to test $H_{null}:Beta_{1}=0$.  But I would guess it is possible to test that hypothesis for total least squares.  So why would this special case of $\lambda = V_{x}/V_{y}$ make $beta_{1}=0$ untestable?

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares#Scale_invariant_methods.  A simple way to answer your first question is to standardize both variables to reduce the problem to the case $v_x=v_y=1$ and (assuming $\beta_1\ne 0$) $\operatorname{Cov}{xy}=\pm 1.$  Upon converting back to the original (pre-standardized) units, the formula for $b{rma}$ immediately follows.

Sorry, I don't quite get it.  I get that plugging lambda=1, v_x=v_y=v' yields: b_or=v'-1v' + sqrt([v'-1v']^2+41cov^2)/(2cov)=>1.  But then how do I "convert back" in a way that yields the ratio of the deviations?

In exactly the same way you would convert any unit of measurement.

Sorry, I probably should have done this before asking the question, but I tried plugging in lambda=(Vy/Vx) instead of (Vx/Vy) and the equation easily simplifies to sdy/sdx.  So unless you think it's not a typo, I think that's the easiest explanation.  Or maybe you've been using the reverse formula the entire time anyways.  Thanks for your patience. I appreciate it.

I didn't even try to apply the formula!  I'm glad you have resolved your question.
